# How to skip fields in a Json file with Python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to read a Json file to transform it into csv
I looked on some stackoverflow questions and it helped me but I still have a little problem.
 There are fields that don't interest me and I don't know how to say to my script to skip these fields.

Here is my code :

```
import csv
import json

x = """{
"year": "2008",
"title": "Movies",
"items": [

{
"title": "The dark knight",
"description": "A batman story"
},

{
"title": "The Mummy: Tomb of the Dragon Emperor",
"description": "A mummy story"

},


{
"title": "Ironman",
"description": "An Avengers story"

}


]
}"""


x = json.loads(x)


for key, value in x.items():
    print(key, value)
```

Of course I chose a very sample and short text to illustrate my example.

When I run that script I get that :

```
(u'items', [{u'description': u'A batman story', u'title': u'The dark knight'}, {u'description': u'A mummy story', u'title': u'The Mummy: Tomb of the Dragon Emperor'}, {u'description': u'An Avengers story', u'title': u'Ironman'}]) (u'title', u'Movies') (u'year', u'2008')
```

And I would like to know how to display only the item's fields and to skip the fields "year" and "title" at the beggining.

So, I would like to get the following output :

```
[{u'description': u'A batman story', u'title': u'The dark knight'}, {u'description': u'A mummy story', u'title': u'The Mummy: Tomb of the Dragon Emperor'}, {u'description': u'An Avengers story', u'title': u'Ironman'}])
```

I need to access only to these fields to write them in a csv file after. 
So do you have an idea how I could do that ?

Thank you very much in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this instead:

```
x = json.loads(x)['items']

for item in x:
    print item['description']
    print item['title']
```

Comment: Thank you it's working fine :D (sorry for the delay of my answer, there was the night in my country)

Answer (score 3):

`json.loads` parses JSON into a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

You can access the "items" key directly:

```
print(x["items"])
```

Comment: Thank you it's working but it displays all the line with the brackets , suppose I want to put the title of the movie in a string variable , like and when I do print(title) I get "The dark knight" as output

Comment: Loop through x["items"] as Kevin has shown, and assign them to a string.